# problema con netbeans desisntalacion

Tags: java

Hola buenas tardes tengo un problema al desinstalar netbeans al momento que entro al panel de control y quiero desinstalarlo no puedo porque sale un recuadro de el JDK 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendrías que descargarte el JDK de Java 6 para poder desinstalarlo según el mensaje.

Comment: A mí me pasa que por una incompatibilidad de mi tarjeta gráfica con mi sistema operativo no me permite desinstalar el netbeans, así que si tienes mas información sería de ayuda si tu caso no es común.

Answer (score 0):

Puede deberse a dos cosas:

1. Desinstalaste el JDK y el programa instalador/desinstalador lo necesita.
2. El desinstalador no encuentra tu instalación del JDK porque no están bien configuradas las variables de sistema (y tal vez alguna vez lo estuvieron).

Si es el caso 1 debes instalar un JDK primero para poderlo desinstalar.

Si es el caso 2 debes configurar tu instalación del JDK mediante el registro de las aplicaciones que lo componen en las variables de sistema apropiadas hay varias formas de hacerlo y podrías hacer otra pregunta al respecto, yo como lo hago es configurando la variable JAVA_HOME en el PATH.